# unique_ptr<char[]> vs vector<char> as a string buffer

Tags: c++, memory, vector, unique-ptr

I've ran into a few scenarios where I need to write a string to a temporary buffer, usually because that's just how the libraries I am using returns strings.

Examples typically look like (with `vector`):

```
std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size);
getString(&buffer[0], buffer_size); //Or buffer.data()
std::string str(&buffer[0]);
```

But I prefer using (with `unique_ptr`):

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[buffer_size]);
getString(buffer.get(), buffer_size);
std::string str(buffer.get());
```

Since I see the first so often, I'm wondering if there's any benefit to using it instead. Which, if any, should be preferred?

Comment: What about using `std::string`'s fill constructor and then accessing memory using `.data()`?

Comment: I feel `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` is rather more restrictive and harder to use than a `std::vector<char>`. Not least of which is that the *vector* stores the *length* of the data.